# Is the CPu temperature of my laptop normal?

Tags: linux, cpu, temperature, elementaryos

I'm using Elementary OS.

When I start the laptop in the morning (the laptop is cold), if i run sensors 36° Celsius. After some time, if i open a browser, the speed fan gets to 2000 rpm and the temperature of the cpu is always between 45-50-55 Celsius (2500-2800 rpm). It's normal?
It can be a overheating issue?

CPU model: Intel core i5-3317u

Comment: What is your CPU model? Have you checked its technical specifications?

Comment: intel core i5-3317u with nvidia gpu 740m

Comment: Have you googled it?

Comment: It says the max temperature are 100 degree celsius

Answer (score 2):

According to this page [Intel Website](https://ark.intel.com/products/65707/Intel-Core-i5-3317U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_60-GHz), that processor will break down at 105 Celsius.

If you have custom cooling your processor will start up much cooler, but laptops normally do not have enough space for the best cooling. If you are still running stock cooling, those temperatures are quite normal under load.

If you are worried about the temperatures, then I would suggest you check for dust blocking the vents(or anything blocking the vents).